# How to produce a bean that need an InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream, cdi, weld

I try to read an Excel file with Apache POI. The project uses CDI. So i need to inject an Handler. This Handler needs a SharedStringTable as constructor parameter. So my constructor looks like this.

```
@Inject
public Handler(SharedStringTable sst) {
    this.sst = sst
}
```

I have started to write a producer for the SharedStringTable but this object needs an inputStream to be produced.

This is the code that i have for the producer :

```
@Produces
public SharedStringTable gets(InjectionPoint ip) {
    // How i can get this InputStream?
    OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(is);
    is.close();
    XSSFReader r = new XSSFREADER(pkg)
    SharedStringTable sst = r.getSharedStringTable();
    return sst;     
}
```

Someone as idea to help me?

Comment: It depends how and when you get the information to instantiate your input stream. Can you give more info on that point?

Comment: The project uses Strut 1 and the inputStream comes from the Form passed to the Struct Action.